# Value of variables not changing universally

Tags: python, variables

I'm very new to classes and wanted to practice by making this code.

Why the variable `p` in `check_Float`'s value is not then transferred to the variable `p` in the bottom block of the code.

```
while p != 3:
    A.questiondef(p)
    print(p)
```

As this value doesn't change, the code will just ask an infinite amount of questions.

```
class B:
    def which_Class(self):
        if i == 0:
            self.class_number = ("Class One")
        elif i == 1:
            self.class_number = ("Class Two")
        elif i == 2:
            self.class_number = ("Class Three")
        else:
            None

    def questiondef(self, p):
        operations = {"x":operator.mul , "-":operator.sub , "/":operator.truediv, "+":operator.add}
        self.num1 = random.randint(1,200)
        self.num2 = random.randint(1,10)
        self.ops = random.choice(list(operations.keys()))
        self.answer = ((operations.get(self.ops))(self.num1, self.num2))
        A.check_Float(p)


    def student_Score(self, score):
        if p == 3:
            print(name ,  "Your score out of 3 is: " , score)
            if i == 0:
                class_1[y][0] = (score)
                class_1[y][1] = (name)
            elif i == 1:
                class_2.append(score)
            elif i == 2:
                class_3.append(score)

            self.score = 0
        else:
            None
    def check_Float(self, p):
        float1 = self.answer%1
        if float1 == 0:
            self.question = int(input("What is {} {} {}?: ".format(self.num1 , self.ops , self.num2)))
            if self.question == self.answer:
                print("\nCorrect\n")
                p = p+1
                return True
            else:
                print("\nIncorrect\n")
                p = p + 1
                return False

        else:
            return False
            A.questiondef(p)

p = 0
class_1 = [["",""],["",""],["",""]]
class_2 = []
class_3 = []
class_number = ""
A = B()
score = 0
import random
import operator
for i in range (3):
    A.which_Class()
    print(A.class_number)
    for y in range(3): #Assuming there are 3 students in a class
        p = 0
        name = input("\nWhat is your name?: " )
        score = 0
        while p != 3:
            A.questiondef(p)
            print(p)

            if p ==3:
                A.student_Score(score)
```

Comment: `A.questiondef(p)` in the `else` block of `check_Float` can never execute because you return beforehand. I don't know if that's the problem, I don't understand the problem description "the variable is not transferred to the bottom".

Comment: The only thing I can decipher from this is that when you change p, you are doing it within scope of a method without returning that new value of p, or even making it available to your instance using `self`. Besides that, I'm pretty lost.

Comment: `p` is local to `Check_Float` as you have it defined as a parameter. You are never updating the global `p`

Comment: sorry for the really bad explanation of the problem. @NathanK , I had to make it a parameter because if i didn't it says p is referenced before assignment. Also when i try to make it a global variable it says it cant be a parameter and global variable. So i'm just really confused on how to approach this.

Comment: @JavedHakim you said you started learning classes. I did not analyze your code, however, if p is something that is being shared across your instance, maybe you should look in to making it an instance attribute?

Comment: Note that Python function arguments follow a _call by value_ semantics. If you **assign** to an argument inside the function, the caller (and the rest of the world outside the function) won't be affected by that. (However, the passed values are _references_, not deep copies, so if you **change a mutable object** that was passed as an argument, that change _will_ be reflected for others that also hold a reference to the same object, e.g. the caller.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **global** keyword 
use like as 
p = 0 at top of code 
then in each function or function in which p is used
you can make p global as 
global p at top of function